# detector confidence

Tags: probability

the situation is as follows: Say, I am going to answer a multiple choice question based on suggestion of my two friends. One gives correct answer 60% percent of the times, the other gives correct answer 40% of the times. Is there any way I can answer a question correctly more than 60% of the time? (in a long run average leaving aside natural variability)

Comment: Are you assuming that the two "correctnesses" are independent of each other?

Comment: yes. and my supplementary concern is that if I always follow what the 60% guy tells me, will I not be amplifying the difference between their confidence.

Comment: You may need to describe the question a little more, for example, how many choices?  If it's more than a "True/False" question, e.g., "which of the following is correct: a, b, c", if one of the friends is wrong, can we assume they choose a wrong answer with equal probability from the set of wrong answers?  Also, I think with "True/False" questions you're doomed, but I'm just being intuitive when I state that.

Comment: Actually, I think you're stuck no matter what; when A (60% probability of being correct) and B (40% probability of being correct) disagree, you're more likely to be right by going with A, and when they agree, you're still going with A, so you always go with A.

Comment: I've seen this in either a home work or a quiz somewhere.

Comment: It's based on Ryan Baker's course - big data in education. He goes past this point while explaining detectors.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, I figured that person B's didn't help, since there was no correlation.  However, I went back to Bays to solve it more rigorously and found an (at least interesting to me) result.

assume N choices, all of which are equally probable

P[ans is 1 | A says 1 AND B says 1] = P[ A says 1 AND B says 1 | ans is 1 ] P[ ans is 1 ] / P[ A says 1 and B says 1 ]

PP[ans is 1 | A says 1 AND B says 1] = (3/5) (2/5) (1/N) / ( (3/5) (2/5) (1/N) + (N-1) (1/N) (1/(N-1)) (2/5) (3/5) ), explanation below

PP[ ans is 1 | A says 1 AND B says 1] = 1 / 2

The other 1/2 chance is spread over all other (the incorrect) answers, but if there are only two choices (i.e. true/false), then in the event that A and B agree, you can guess either, it does not matter.  You have less confidence if B agrees.

*explanation of P[]

since A is right 3/5 and B is right 2/5,
P[ A says 1 AND B says 1 | ans is 1 ] = P[ A 1 | ans 1 ] P[ B 1 | ans 1 ] = (3/5) (2/5)

since the a priori probability of answer 1 is 1/N, 
P[ A says 1 and B says 1 ] = P[ A says 1 AND B says 1 | ans is 1 ] P[ ans is 1 ] = (3/5) (2/5) (1/N)

P[ A says 1 and B says 1 ] = P[ A 1 and B 1 | ans 1 ] P[ ans 1 ] + P[ A 1 and B 1 | ans NOT 1 ] P[ ans NOT 1 ]
since there are N-1 ways for the answer to not be 1, each with a priori probability 1/N, but only a (1/(N-1)) chance to be wrong in such a way to suggest the answer is 1, and the probabilities of being wrong are A 2/5 and B 3/5,
P[ A says 1 and B says 1 ] = (3/5) (2/5) (1/N)  + (N-1) (1/N) (1/(N-1)) (2/5) (3/5)